# Batch: Avoid whitespaces and duplicate entries

Tags: windows, batch-file, text-processing, wmic

I have written a batch script that scans through every IP address in the network and fetches Host Name and MAC Address associated with that IP address.

Script:

```
@echo off

setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

    for /L %%y in (73,1,79) do (
    for /L %%z in (1,1,254) do (

    set "node=172.22.%%y.%%z"

    ping -n 1 !node! | find "TTL=" > NUL
    if not errorlevel 1 (

    for /f "delims=" %%a in (
        'wmic /node:"!node!" computersystem get name /format:csv ^| find /i "!node!"'
    ) do (
    for /f "tokens=1-2 delims=," %%b in ("%%a") do (
        set "_name=%%c"
    ))

    for /f "tokens=1-2 delims==" %%a in ('nbtstat -A "!node!"'
    ) do (

    set "_mac=%%b"
        echo !node!,!_name!,!_mac! >> output.txt

    )
    )
))
```

The output of the scan displays more than one results for each IP, of which only one result is useful and that contains the MAC address, while other ones are duplicate entries and having a whitespace in the place of MAC Address.

**Output:**

```
172.22.73.3,WORKSTATION4, 
172.22.73.3,WORKSTATION4, 
172.22.73.3,WORKSTATION4, 
172.22.73.3,WORKSTATION4, 
172.22.73.3,WORKSTATION4, 
172.22.73.3,WORKSTATION4, 
172.22.73.3,WORKSTATION4, 
172.22.73.3,WORKSTATION4, 
172.22.73.3,WORKSTATION4, 
172.22.73.3,WORKSTATION4, 
172.22.73.3,WORKSTATION4, 
172.22.73.3,WORKSTATION4, 
172.22.73.3,WORKSTATION4, 
172.22.73.3,WORKSTATION4, 
172.22.73.3,WORKSTATION4, 
172.22.73.3,WORKSTATION4, 00-17-7C-11-3A-5F

172.22.73.3,WORKSTATION4, 
172.22.73.13,WORKSTATION1, 
172.22.73.13,WORKSTATION1, 
172.22.73.13,WORKSTATION1, 
172.22.73.13,WORKSTATION1, 
172.22.73.13,WORKSTATION1, 
172.22.73.13,WORKSTATION1, 
172.22.73.13,WORKSTATION1, 
172.22.73.13,WORKSTATION1, 
172.22.73.13,WORKSTATION1, 
172.22.73.13,WORKSTATION1, 
172.22.73.13,WORKSTATION1, 
172.22.73.13,WORKSTATION1, 
172.22.73.13,WORKSTATION1, 
172.22.73.13,WORKSTATION1, 
172.22.73.13,WORKSTATION1, 
172.22.73.13,WORKSTATION1, 
172.22.73.13,WORKSTATION1, 00-14-5E-1E-5A-8E

172.22.73.13,WORKSTATION1, 
172.22.73.15,MANDAR-PC, 
172.22.73.15,MANDAR-PC, 
172.22.73.15,MANDAR-PC, 
172.22.73.15,MANDAR-PC, 
172.22.73.15,MANDAR-PC, 
172.22.73.15,MANDAR-PC, 
172.22.73.15,MANDAR-PC, 
172.22.73.15,MANDAR-PC, 
172.22.73.15,MANDAR-PC, 
172.22.73.15,MANDAR-PC, 
172.22.73.15,MANDAR-PC, 
172.22.73.15,MANDAR-PC, 
172.22.73.15,MANDAR-PC, 
172.22.73.15,MANDAR-PC, 
172.22.73.15,MANDAR-PC, 
172.22.73.15,MANDAR-PC, 
172.22.73.15,MANDAR-PC, 
172.22.73.15,MANDAR-PC, 
172.22.73.15,MANDAR-PC, 
172.22.73.15,MANDAR-PC, 00-1E-0B-9D-DD-E9
```

Whereas, the ideal output should have been like:

```
172.22.73.3,WORKSTATION4, 00-17-7C-11-3A-5F
172.22.73.13,WORKSTATION1, 00-14-5E-1E-5A-8E
172.22.73.15,MANDAR-PC, 00-1E-0B-9D-DD-E9
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace

```
echo !node!,!_name!,!_mac! >> output.txt
```

with

```
if not "!_mac!"=="" echo !node!,!_name!,!_mac! >> output.txt
```

**EDIT** here is the complete code, that works for me:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
for /L %%y in (73,1,79) do (
  for /L %%z in (1,1,254) do (
    set "node=172.22.%%y.%%z"
    ping -n 1 !node! | find "TTL=" > NUL
    if not errorlevel 1 (
      for /f "delims=" %%a in ('wmic /node:"!node!" computersystem get name /format:csv ^| find /i "!node!"') do (
        for /f "tokens=1-2 delims=," %%b in ("%%a") do set "_name=%%c"
      )
      for /f "tokens=1-2 delims==" %%a in ('nbtstat -A "!node!"') do (
        set "_mac=%%b"
        if not "!_mac!"=="" echo !node!,!_name!,!_mac: =! >> output.txt
      )
    )
  )
)
```

Comment: Tried that too. It is not working at all. Same results.
Actually, it is displaying everything, but the MAC address entries.

Comment: ? everything but the lines you are interested in? Try to remove the `not`. Else can you check, what `!_mac!` contains?

Comment: I tried removing `not`, it didn't create any output file. Also tried checking `_mac` variable (without removing `not`), it created an output file that contained multiple lines saying `Echo is off`.

Comment: So the variable is empty. Fine. Then `if not "!_mac!"=="" ...` should work. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Again, the same thing. Output file is not created.

Comment: Works fine here. I put the whole code into my answer to avoid any misunderstandings.

Comment: That's perfect! Except the carriage return which is being displayed at the end of each MAC address displayed. That can be sorted out though. Many Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I changed the last three lines of your code above the `)` so see if that helps.

```
@echo off

setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

    for /L %%y in (73,1,79) do (
    for /L %%z in (1,1,254) do (

    set "node=172.22.%%y.%%z"

    ping -n 1 !node! | find "TTL=" > NUL
    if not errorlevel 1 (

    for /f "delims=" %%a in (
        'wmic /node:"!node!" computersystem get name /format:csv ^| find /i "!node!"'
    ) do (
    for /f "tokens=1-2 delims=," %%b in ("%%a") do (
        set "_name=%%c"
    ))

    for /f "tokens=1-2 delims==" %%a in ('nbtstat -A "!node!"'
    ) do (

      set "_mac="
      set "_mac=%%b"
      if defined _mac >> output.txt echo !node!,!_name!,!_mac!

    )
    )
))
```